# Getting Feed data from Facebook API in a specific type

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get my feed data those type will be only video using facebook graph api.

I am using this way but not work

```
me/feed/?type=video&fields=shares,likes.summary(true),created_time,comments.summary(true),
actions,name,description,link,picture,type,message,status_type,story,from
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/feed/#read

There is no such thing as a `type` parameter/filter. You need to use the `filter` parameter, with a value of `app_2392950137` (video) as outlined in the docs, e.g.

```
/me/feed?filter=app_2392950137&fields=shares,likes.summary(true),created_time,comments.summary(true),
```

actions,name,description,link,picture,type,message,status_type,story,from